# Reuse Razor Partial View with Form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, reusability

I have a partial view that has a form to post to a controller. I can include it into another view using @Html.RenderPartial.

The problem is that the parent view is linked with another controller. And the partial view post to its orginal controller.

Is it possible and how to write partial views with form that supports reuse?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the form's `action` url (or action name) as a parameter to the partial view.

Comment: Worked for me by passing the action name and implementing the action in the parent controller. Thanks.